# How can I use a different upscaling method in dx11?

Tags: directx11

I need to upscale images using the 'box' scaling algorithm as the pixel art textures in my game don't scale well with bilinear because of the blur. Either that, or use high res pictures which would be undesirable and inflate the size by many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you just draw 2D images as textures (a.k.a. "sprites") as is done with `SpriteBatch` in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). You can specify the sampler state to use `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT` to turn off all the filtering.

```
const float border[4] = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };

// PointWrap
CD3D11_SAMPLER_DESC desc(D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT,
    D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP,
    0.f, maxAnisotropy, D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER, border, 0.f, FLT_MAX);

// PointClamp
CD3D11_SAMPLER_DESC desc(D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT,
    D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP,
    0.f, maxAnisotropy, D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER, border, 0.f, FLT_MAX);
```